# Trying to find golang equivalent of this perl array

Tags: go

I'm a perl scripter guy learning go. In perl, arrays can be easily created without the need of commas and quotation marks like:

```
my @array = qw/
Hello
World
Won't
you 
be 
my 
friend
/;
```

Does golang offer this simplicity? Or do I have to use the brackets?

Comment: What's wrong with brackets?

Comment: I would not call this kind of syntax "simple" it's plain misleading and unclear in my opinion.

Comment: Most people would call Perl's `qw` operator (along with about 90% of the other language features) obscure complexity.  They enable writing short code, but the make readability a nightmare.

Comment: Why did I get dinged 3 points for asking this question?

Answer (score 2):

Go does not have special syntax like Perl's qw, but you can use [strings.Fields](http://godoc.org/strings#Fields) to split a string into a slice of strings:

```
    a := strings.Fields(`
      Hello 
      World 
      Won't 
      you 
      be 
      my 
      friend`)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F7O2sQHzDYc).

The idiomatic approach is to use a composite literal:

```
a := []string{"Hello", "World", "Won't", "you", "be", "my", "friend"}
```

Comment: While the answer is good, I still think @Flimzy was better at asking because of trying to explain why the OPs approach is bad. Resist to downvote though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the only correct way to form that <strike>array</strike> slice in Go is:

```
slice := []string{"Hello", "World", "Won't", "you", "be", "my", "friend"}
```

This is the standard way to create a string slice. It's 100% readable. It offers no surprises.

By comparsion, IMO, the only correct way to form that array in Perl would be:

```
my @array = ( "Hello", "World", "Won't", "you", "be", "my", "friend" );
```

The `qw` operator, while widely understood among initiated Perl programmers, is non-intuitive.  Yes, it allows you to save a few keystrokes. But code should be written for readability, not write-ability.  Most code is read 10x more than it is written, by some estimates. In some cases, it may be read hundreds or thousands of times more than its written (think core library components).  So why on earth would you sacrifice readability to save a few keystrokes?

Even if you decide that `qw` is widely enough understood within the Perl community to justify its use in Perl (a strong case *can* be made), this argument certainly does not carry over into Go.  Go abhors clever shortcuts, favoring code readability.

Of course there *are* "clever" alternatives, like the one provided in @CeriseLimón's answer, but they decrease readability.  If I came across `strings.Fields` in that context in some code I was reading, it would interrupt the flow of reading the code. I'd have to stop and ponder "Why did the author use this?  What's the special case here?  Why can't a standard slice declaration be used?"  Then after a minute or two, I'd probably realize "The author was just being overly clever for no real reason. Pfft", then I'd have to back up in my code reading, and re-trace my steps to regain flow.

Clever is the enemy of good, readable code.

Answer (score 0):

I completely understand folk who yearn for `@langs = qw(fortran pascal perl go)` - it's one of the Perl idioms I use most  and therefore find completely clear.

Go also values brevity, but this is one area where you can't get the compiler to help, it has to be done at run-time. There's a price to be paid for that.

e.g.

```
langs := strings.Split("fortran pascal perl go ...", " ")
```

[try this](https://play.golang.org/p/fkLAIuTr5jB)

Answer (score 0):

As shown by [Cerise Limón's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313614/244128), you can use [`strings.Fields(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) along with a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) for similar style/effect of your Perl code, regardless of go idioms/best-practices:

```
func main() {
    arr := strings.Fields(`
Hello
World
Won't
you 
be 
my 
friend
`)

    fmt.Printf("OK: arr=%q", arr)
    // OK: arr=["Hello" "World" "Won't" "you" "be" "my" "friend"]
}
```

And yes, the above is [what `go fmt` outputs](https://play.golang.org/p/rsFsdkIHFgc) =)